# How to count the number of dates in a dateTime list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an MVC project. I have a list of dates of when a `username` was created. The list is of type `DateTime`.

Now, I want to show how many `usernames` was created within the past 12 months.

I'm trying to show this in the `ViewModel`. I can count how many there are by doing something like

```
@{ int NumofUserNames = Model.SomethingHere.Count;
}
```

But this counts **ALL** of the items. How do I write it to show the dates within this year (past 365 days)

In c#

**Update**: The view will show how many users created in the past 12 months so I meant in the past 365 from the point the user is viewing it.

Comment: in the last 365 days, as the code will not change but it will always show "in the last 12 months"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion everyone. I have made an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers available:

- For the current year:

  ```
  @{ 
      int currentYear = System.DateTime.Today.Year; 
      int NumofUserNames = Model.Where(x => x.Year == currentYear).Count();
   }
  ```
- For the last 365 days:

  ```
  @{ 
      DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-365); 
      int NumofUserNames = Model.Where(x => x >= startDate).Count();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I have a property for the Start Date. How would I show if the date date is between 6 -12 months?

Comment: Should be `Count()` because `IEnumerable` doesn't have a `Count` property.

Comment: @user290339 If you use a property you would write `x => x.StartDate.Year == currentYear)`. If you are looking for a range you should could use the property several times (like in an if clause) with start of range and end of range),

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
int NumofUserNames = Model.SomethingHere.Count(c => c > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1));
```

Comment: Even better: Use `(c => c.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)`, so you don't have to change it in 2017.

Comment: Question is confusingly worded but does mention _this year "past 365 days"_ so probably `c > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)`

Comment: Subject to interpretion I guess, but in my book, "this year" is not "the past 365 days".

Comment: @stuartd Nice idea. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

1.For this year

```
int NumofUserNames = Model.SomethingHere.Count(x=>x.Year==DateTime.Today.Year);
```

2.For past 365 days

```
int NumofUserNames = Model.SomethingHere.Count(x=>x.Year>DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1));
```

Comment: That second one should be `x > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)`